# Creating a new Jenkins job with python Requests

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I used this successfully:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>" "http://USER:PASSWORD@JENKINS_HOST/createItem?name=NEW_JOB_NAME"
```

I converted it to this python code:

```
url     = "http://USER:PASS@HOST/createItem"
payload = { 'name' : 'NEW_JOB_NAME' }
headers = {"Content-Type:application/xml"}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Where should I put the `"<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>"` part ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to split up the GET parameters as payload, you need to put the GET parameters with the rest of the URI. The payload should instead consist of the POST data (the "body" of the HTTP request, the `-d` argument to cURL).

I also extracted the authentication to requests' preferred syntax.

```
url     = 'http://HOST/createItem?name=NEW_JOB_NAME'
auth    = ('USER', 'PASS')
payload = '<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/xml"}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

To confirm the result, you could add these lines:

```
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce chelmertz but it throws an error: File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 411, in prepare_headers
    self.headers = CaseInsensitiveDict((to_native_string(name), value) for name, value in headers.items())
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @KostasDemiris ah, sorry, you got an error that I reused :) See the `headers` after my edit.

Comment: Niceee! Works perfect. Thanks again.